# AndroidTest folder doesn't show on AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm setting up Android app structure with Gradle and Android Studio and Espresso UI testing for a project.

No matter what I try, the androidTest folder never appears in AndroidStudio's project structure.

Project (root) build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

App build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "es.unizar.vv.mobile.catmdedit.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'

            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/main/resources'
            }
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }

        test.setRoot("test")

        androidTest.setRoot("androidTest")
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
}
```

How project structure looks:

[image]

How project structure actually is:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the **Test Artifact** within your **Build Variants** to **Android Instrumentation Tests**.

The Build Variants tab can be found in the bottom left side of the Android Studio window above Favorites. Clicking on the tab should open a pane with your modules and build variants for those modules. Above the modules is a Test Artifact dropdown which you should change to Android Instrumentation Tests.

Comment: I did as you said, there is the pane and the app module with build variant either debug or release, test artifact: android instrumentation tests, but in my android project structure the androidTest folder doesn't yet appear.

Comment: I'm not sure then. My suggestion helped me with my similar problem.

Comment: Omg, I'm sorry, actually you were right, I only needed to add this to gradle:

    `androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')

        androidTest {
            java{
                srcDirs 'src/androidTest/java'
            }
        }`

And then in build variants > Android Instrumentation Tests it appears!

Thank you!

Comment: This has changed in a later version of Android Studio. The accepted answer isn't applicable any more, the pane isn't there any more. 6uitar6reat6od's answer does work.

Answer (score 26):

This was happening for me because I had my current variant set to `release`. Changing it back to `debug` and doing a Gradle sync caused `androidTest` folders to show up again.

Comment: yeaah it really helps, man you're CHAMP! Spent 2 days looking for this!

Comment: For me it is the other way around, it shows up for `release` but not for `debug`. :-(

Comment: @BartLouwers just change your `testBuildType` property

Answer (score 18):

### You just need to add these line in build.gradle file

After doing lots of R&D I found proper solution. Now it's working..

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
        test { java.srcDirs = ['src/test/java'] }
        androidTest { java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java'] }
    }
}
```

After adding above code "androidTest" folder is now appearing!!

Comment: still not generated

Comment: @ManojBehera maybe you have to create the folder yourself. Because this solution did work for me (I had created a *androidTest* folder manually before trying this solution). So after this, I was able to see my *androidTest* folder in Android Studio.

Comment: @Sufian That fixed it for me; thanks. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Just in case somebody is still stuck with this issues, I will suggest you just recreate the folders your self which is extremely easy than I thought! here: follow the steps in the photo.[image]

don't forget to switch from android to project and like that you will have the same directory tree like in the picture below and simple create the folder and files, after which you can then switch back to android and it will give you the same directory tree as on the right side of the image.

and your ExampleInstrumentedTest class can look like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

}
```

and the ExampleUnitTest class can look like this:

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    int addition(){
        return 60;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open the `Gradle` pane on the right side.

Under
`app > Tasks > build` double click `assembleAndroidTest` 
and it'll generate test packages.

```
:app:packageDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleDebugAndroidTest
:app:assembleAndroidTest
```

Here is it all:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
androidTest.setRoot("androidTest")
```

This path is relative to the build.gradle file. Just remove it and gradle will pick your src/androidTest folder automatically as your project follows the default file structure.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to add these lines to your **build.gradle** file :

```
androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')

androidTest  { 
    java { 
        srcDirs 'src/androidTest/java' 
    } 
}
```