# How to (re)configure androidTest folder as the instrumented tests folder?

Tags: android, android-studio

The project in Android Studio has instrumentation tests in the androidTest folder in a single class and used to work ok. I made a change to the project and now the test class fails to find its dependencies (specified in the app Gradle build file) unless I change androidTestCompile to compile (which obviously I cannot). The source listing is covered in red errors re @RunWith, AndroidJUnit4, @Test, InstrumentationRegistry, etc.

I cannot configure the instrumentation configuration in the IDE as the field to specify the class says the class does not exist (it does).

The ultimate cause of this was changes made to move the tests (JVM and Android) from an incorrect package to the same package as the application - that did not break the JVM tests, but has broken the Android tests. The test files are in the right folders, and the correct package name (matching) is specified in the class files. It looks that the project has "forgotten" that the androidTest folder is where it is, but where is that configured?

I've tried rebuilding the project, and restarting the IDE after invalidating its caches. Neither helped.

Anyone have any ideas how I might fix this? I suspect I may need to delete all the IDE files and reimport from Gradle, but it would be nice if there was an easier way.

Comment: I made numerous attempts to fix this with no success. But then several days later without me doing anything deliberate to fix it, the problem resolved itself.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292783/androidtest-folder-doesnt-show-on-androidstudio

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. The reason for this is because the build variant (Flavor) was not the correct one. I had it on **"staging" instead of "debug"** witch it's set up as the default. Make sure to change that on the left side of your IDEA where it says "Build Variants", or if you are using the newer version, look for the Hammer with the four squares also on the left side.